# What are some heat-tolerant plants you can grow in outdoor hydroponics?

Tags: hydroponic, heat

I live in Houston. I just built an outdoor hydroponics setup. I've tried growing basil in it, but I think it's too hot for that. I'm going to try tomatoes now, but I hear they're not very heat-tolerant either.

What things can I grow in hydroponics when it's 90+ degrees outside?

Comment: I'm not a hydroponic gardener, but have you evaluated peppers, artichokes, watermelon, okra, sunflowers, and such? With regard to tomatoes, is your information about heat with regard to tomatoes generally, or with regard to hydroponic tomatoes specifically?

Comment: Also, have you considered cowpeas, peanuts, sweet potatoes, yardlong beans, and squash?